# How to play a playlist continously?

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, vlc

I have a video file which is 20 seconds long. I cut this video file into segments like

```
video_file_0 -> starts at 0:00, ends at 0:02
video_file_1 -> starts at 0:02, ends at 0:04
video_file_2 -> starts at 0:04, ends at 0:06
video_file_3 -> starts at 0:06, ends at 0:08
video_file_4 -> starts at 0:08, ends at 0:10
video_file_5 -> starts at 0:10, ends at 0:12
video_file_6 -> starts at 0:12, ends at 0:14
video_file_7 -> starts at 0:14, ends at 0:16
video_file_8 -> starts at 0:16, ends at 0:18
video_file_9 -> starts at 0:18, ends at 0:20
```

So my question is, how can I play these video files continously in a single window exactly like playing the whole video file from 0:00 to 0:20, without closing and reopening windows in every switching between video files. Can I use ffplay, ffmpeg or vlcj for this functionality?

I tried

```
find -type f -name "video_file_*" | while read f; do ffplay -autoexit -- "$f"; done
```

But this code closes and reopens the window between every video file, I don't want that. How can I do that?

EDIT: I am building a Java project which the streams are shown inside the JFrame. So I want this functionality is shown inside the JFrame.

Comment: Doesn't `vlc video_file_*` open all of them? You can set the playlist to repeat. Will that do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. vlc video_file_* opens all of them with a little blackout between every file. But I am building a Java project using vlcj which plays streams in a JFrame. So vlc doesn't work for me.

Comment: I guess I should have read "using vlcj which plays streams in a JFrame" whatever it is, and if it really matters this should be added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `mpv --gapless-audio=yes --loop-playlist=inf video_file_*` to enable Gapless playback as [documented in the manual](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#audio):

> ```
> --gapless-audio=<no|yes|weak>
> ```
>
> Try to play consecutive audio files with no silence or disruption at
> the point of file change. Default: weak.
>
> `no`: Disable gapless audio.
>
> `yes`: The audio device is opened using parameters chosen for the
> first file played and is then kept open for gapless playback. This
> means that if the first file for example has a low sample rate, then
> the following files may get resampled to the same low sample rate,
> resulting in reduced sound quality. If you play files with different
> parameters, consider using options such as --audio-samplerate and
> --audio-format to explicitly select what the shared output format will be.
>
> `weak`: Normally, the audio device is kept open (using the format it
> was first initialized with). If the audio format the decoder output
> changes, the audio device is closed and reopened.
> [...]

along:

> ```
> --loop-playlist=<N|inf|force|no>, --loop-playlist
> ```
>
> Loops playback N times. A value of 1 plays it one time (default), 2
> two times, etc. inf means forever. no is the same as 1 and disables
> looping. If several files are specified on command line, the entire
> playlist is looped. `--loop-playlist` is the same as
> `--loop-playlist=inf`.

`mpv` also takes care of not creating any flicker in the video window.

For a longer bu reasonable playlist `video_file_*` can be replaced (with adequate variant of `sort`) with `$(printf '%s\n' video_file_* | sort -V)`, but that wouldn't handle spaces & other chars.

So using `find` + `xargs` allows to handle any special character (which might still choke *mpv* itself) but would disrupt *tty* control for interactive control, so here it's artificially restored with `</dev/tty`:

```
find -type f -name 'video_file_*' -print0 | sort -V -z | xargs -0 -- sh -c 'exec mpv </dev/tty --gapless-audio=yes --loop-playlist=inf -- "$@"'
```

Note: recent versions of `mpv` already redirect `/dev/tty` back themselves.

---

UPDATE: `mpv` has a `--wid=` option to embed itself into an other window. So if spawned from an application having prepared a window for this it could just be given by the application the parameter for the target window. [From the manual](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#window):

> ```
> --wid=<ID>
> ```
>
> This tells mpv to attach to an existing window. If a VO is selected
> that supports this option, it will use that window for video output.
> mpv will scale the video to the size of this window, and will add
> black bars to compensate if the aspect ratio of the video is
> different.
>
> On X11, the ID is interpreted as a Window on X11.
> [...]

So without requiring much code, on X11, using `xwininfo` to retrieve a window's Window id, eg: `0xdeadbeef`, one can use `mpv --wid=0xdeadbeef ...` to embed it in that window. For example it works fine, including controls, on a simple `xterm`. Any more advanced use should probably involve [embedding *libmpv* into other programs](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#embedding-into-other-programs-libmpv). Here are also pointers to X11's [XReparentWindow](https://manpages.debian.org/XReparentWindow.3) (but `mpv` should be kept in charge of doing this):

- [Embedding an X11 window, belonging to an independent process launched by me, into my own window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335469/embedding-an-x11-window-belonging-to-an-independent-process-launched-by-me-int)
- [XLib: Reparenting a Java window with popups properly translated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646544/xlib-reparenting-a-java-window-with-popups-properly-translated) (but AFAIK, OP's goal is the other way around)
- [`xdotool`](https://manpages.debian.org/xdotool.1) has a `windowreparent` command.

Comment: looks like recent versions of mpv redirect tty themselves (so not needed)

Comment: Hello A.B, thanks for your great answer! I understand very well, mpv is working great and there is no blackouts, flickers etc. in the video window. But can I embed this player in a JFrame?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335469/embedding-an-x11-window-belonging-to-an-independent-process-launched-by-me-int

Comment: edited answer for the `--wid=`option

Comment: Thanks for your update, when I run the Java application I can grab the window id by running the xwininfo command in terminal and selecting the desired jFrame, and passing window Id of the frame to the --wid option. In this way output of mpv can be embedded in the frame. But is there a way to automate this process? In my java application, can I grab the frame's window id with the help of some java api? I have used `xprop -root | grep " + "\"_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)\"" + "|cut -d ' ' -f 5` but this code outputs the window id of the IDE instead of jFrame.

Comment: You could ask a question on Stackoverflow on how to have your Java code know the right information. If it's creating the Window, it must already have a way to know what's needed.

Comment: Ok I will think about that. Thanks.

Comment: But if the JFrame structure doesn't translate to an X11/whatever equivalent as Window Id, then obviously this won't work. It has to be turned into or created inside something providing its own Window Id.